# Give an example of a set $S$ whose support function is not continuous on $R^n$.

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, optimization, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$.

The support function of set $A$ is defined as the following

$$
S_A(x)=\sup_{y \in A} x^Ty
$$
where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Notice that when $A$ is bounded the function is continuous.

Give an example of a set except $S\neq \mathbb{R}^n$ whose support function is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2993397/provide-a-counterexample-that-shows-supremum-over-an-unbounded-set-is-not-contin               Why create a new question?

Comment: Because I made a mistake and I was not clear in expressing my question.